# Cannot use table classname when using Bootstrap/React Bootstrap in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, bootstrap-4

I want to include the react-bootstrap theme in my ReactJs-Spring project.

I have linked the resource based on the tutorial on its website showed as follow:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@latest/dist/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@latest/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-bootstrap/0.31.0/react-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

And I code the table element like this:

```
<table className="table table-striped">                         
   <tr>
     <th>Name</th>
     <th>Age</th>
     <th>Years</th>
     <th>Delete</th>
   </tr>                           
</table>
```

But on the website, it doesn't have any change:
[image: table]

Can anyone help me solve this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `thead` and `tbody` elements, like :

```
<table className="table table-striped">
  <thead>            
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Years</th>
      <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>    
  </thead>  
  <tbody>
    ...
  </tbody>                       
</table>
```